# Correct way to hyphenate "bourguignon"?

Tags: typographie, trait-d-union

I am a bit in doubt about what is the correct way to divide/hyphenate the word "bourguignon".

Is it: *bour-guignon* or *bourg-uignon* or something completely different?

Answer (score 7):

You must hyphenate it on each syllable. Here, the word has 3 syllables :

> Bour-gui-gnon [bur-ɡi-ɲɔ̃]